# Firebase: for notifications use childEventLisetener or SingleEvent?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app that uses Firebase for the backend. In my database, I have a section called `USER_NOTIFICATIONS` which gets populated with some information when user's post gets liked.

Now, in the app, should I have a `ChildEventListener` that gets triggered any time a notification happens or should I have a `SingleValueEventListener` inside a function and call it every 20 seconds inside a `Runnable`? Is it expensive to run `SingleEventListener` in a `Runnable`?

Comment: This is not a question that can be answered without seeing things like data structure, code of the listeners, frequency of the writes and the size of each delta. That's why I described the system behavior below, in hopes that it allows you to figure out the best approach for your app yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to your app to respond to changes in the database, in which case you should use `ChildEventListener`. You can specify different behavior for 4 actions (`onChildAdded`, `onChildChanged`, `onChildMoved` and `onChildRemoved`).

Comment: I understand but I don't want users to be bombarded with notifications. So is it expensive if I run `SingleValueEvent` inside a `Runnable`?

Comment: It's not expensive to do that, the Thread you are spawning is mostly just idling. Just be careful to clear the Handler when you no longer need it to prevent a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the resource usage of a listener comes from the data it reads. When you attach a listener to a location, it reads the data from that location and fires the relevant events.

If you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` that's all it does. But if you use `addValueEventListener` or `addChildEventListener`, the listener stays active and will also be called if the data is updated afterwards.

a listener on a piece of data that never changes is quite cheap. But keeping a listener on data that changes frequently is as expensive as the size of the data changes.

In other words: there is no way to tell what to do without knowing all of the above. Without knowing those, I'd go for the simplest possible approach, put some measurements in place, and optimize as you discover more about your app's behavior.